# Free up workers for processing while waiting for long DB queries (uWSGI)?

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi, gevent, pymysql

I am maintaining API server for my company which runs a python **flask** app in **uwsgi** on top of **nginx**.

```
...

@app.route('/getquick', methods=["GET"])
def GET_GET_IP_DATA():
    sp_final = "CALL sp_quick()"
    cursor.execute(sp_final)

@app.route('/get_massive_log', methods=["POST"])
def get_massive_log():
    sp_final = "CALL sp_slow()"
    cursor.execute(sp_final)
...
```

While the first request **/getquick** gets processed very quickly, **/get_massive_log** can take up to five seconds due to a rather **long and complex mySQL query**. The server can handle few of these queries but starts creating broken pipe errors when called to much.

**The problem is, the other /getquick requests get blocked by these long I/O requests.**

My manager suggested that I use **gevent** to somehow free up the server to process the other requests while waiting for the mySQL queries, but I am not sure if I am looking in the correct direction.

I am using **pymysql** to run queries, which google seems to suggest to work with **gevent on top of uwsgi**, but I have not been able to produce better results with it.

I have googled for days now, and while I am trying to understand threads, concurrency, asynchronous requests, I don't know where to start digging to find a solution. Is it even possible? Any suggestions or even pointers to where to research would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT :** Perhaps my questions wasn't too clear, so I'll try to restate it:

**What's the best way to free up workers for processing other requests while waiting for long database queries with uwsgi?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn about [Uwsgi offloading](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/articles/OffloadingWebsocketsAndSSE.html#uwsgi-offloading)

> Offloading is a way to optimize tiny tasks, delegating them to one or
>   more threads.
>
> These threads run such tasks in a non-blocking/evented way allowing
>   for a huge amount of concurrency.

You can read about offloading subsystem in the [docs](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/OffloadSubsystem.html)

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about offloading! Although what would be the point of using gevent with uwsgi?

Comment: Did a quick search on uwsgi offloading, there seems to be little extra information beyond the documentation (which is really brief due to the feature being apparently new and experimental).

Comment: Okay, so offloading turns out to be for static file transfers and I don't think this would help me with waiting for pymysql queries (I/O on the machine or another server).